# can't list file in docker in docker (dind)

Tags: docker

I face this strange issue and can't explain why.

```
$ docker run -d --name dind --privileged --net=host -v `pwd`:/app -w /app docker:stable-dind
fe66d6e7e5effcf15e439a332a2368fddab810e9bc8ac3445392c8e56b0aa38a

$ docker exec dind ls
Dockerfile

$ docker exec dind docker run -v `pwd`:/app -w /app alpine ls 


$ docker exec dind docker build -t demo .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  521.7kB
Step 1/24 : FROM alpine
```

So why I can't see my files in docker container which running in docker?

Why it can read the file `Dockerfile` with command `docker build`, but not `docker run`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `pwd` in your code will be parsed in your host machine, not in the container, so `the container which in the container` get the current directory of host machine, not current directory of container machine, you can prove it by change following command from:

```
$ docker exec dind docker run -v `pwd`:/app -w /app alpine ls
```

to

```
$ docker exec dind docker run -v /app:/app -w /app alpine ls
```

Then, you will see your Dockerfile output. FYI.